# How to get value Drive from selecteditem on combobox and interact with listbox just for the selected item

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox, selecteditem

I have been trying to figure this out so far 3 hours and could not get any way out, therefore i need help. Here is what I am trying:
I want to be able to select the Drive and hold the value of that, therefore, at the same time I want it to throw the details that I am trying to get such"free space , type, availability..etc"

```
InitializeComponent();
foreach (var Drives in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
{
    DriveInfo DriveInf = new DriveInfo(Drives);
    if (DriveInf.IsReady == true)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(DriveInf.Name);
        // to get info for the selected drive
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items.Add("Drive Name: " + DriveInf.Name);
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items.Add("Total Size: " + DriveInf.TotalSize);
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items.Add("Available Space: " + DriveInf.AvailableFreeSpace);
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items.Add("Total Free Space: " + DriveInf.TotalFreeSpace);
         }           
     } 
}
```

Comment: You are setting the `SelectedItem` to whatever `ListBox.Items.Add` returns, which is an `Integer`. Try using `SelectedIndex` if you really want to set to that item, but is that what you want to do?

Comment: I've also tried using selectedindex, but no luck! and yes it is exactly what i want to do. SelectedIndex isnt working either for me

Answer (score 1):

So you want to be able to choose a drive from the combo box, and upon selection of drive from combo box populate a listbox with the drive info?

It sounds like you need to have an event handler for comboBox1.SelectionChanged event.
I don't have access to my IDE right now so the following isn't exactly copy and paste ready, but it'll give you an idea of what you need to do.

Here's what I would do: I would make a property for your form

```
private List<DriveInfo> driveInfoList = new List<DriveInfo>();
```

Then after your initialize component method I would put

```
foreach (var Drives in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())    {
    DriveInfo DriveInf = new DriveInfo(Drives);
    if (DriveInf.IsReady == true)
    {
        driveInfoList.Add(DriveInf);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(DriveInf.Name);
    } 
}
```

Then I would put an event handler like such and make sure that your comboBox1's SelectionChanged event is hooked up to it:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //or whatever form the event arguments take.
{
    listBox1.Clear(); //or whatever clears the listbox of current items.
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {        
        DriveInfo driveInfo = (from DriveInfo d in driveInfoList where d.Name == comboBox1.Text select d).First(); //or whatever you need to do to get the corresponding item from the list.

        listBox1.Items.Add("Drive Name: " + d.Name);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Total Size: " + DriveInf.TotalSize);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Available Space: " + DriveInf.AvailableFreeSpace);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Total Free Space: " + DriveInf.TotalFreeSpace);
     }
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: everything sounds ok but how do I need to use this part,DriveInfo driveInfo = (from DriveInfo d in driveInfoList where d.Name == comboBox1.Text select d).First();  i did not understand the concept.why so complicated.

Comment: The reason you need that is because you need to find a way to locate the driveinfo object in the list having the same name as the selected text from the combobox. If you wanted, you could do a foreach loop over the objects in the list, compare the names in an if statement, and when the object's name matches the combobox selection populate the listbox... But using a Linq query is much cleaner. Take a few minutes looking over that Linq query in the example I gave you to figure out how it works. It's really not so bad, especially if you have any knowledge of SQL. Linq queries will serve you well!

Comment: The linq query is everything inside the parentheses before `.First();`. The reason you need `.First();` is because Linq queries return a collection of objects, even if there is only one object in the collection. So `.First()` will actually get us a DriveInfo object.

Comment: aha,I was also asking to myself why did he used that sql code in vb:D